# how to construct a dictionary from two lists mapping that key to the value at the corresponding index in the list of values in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

if I have two lists:

keys = [("a", 2), ("b", 0), ("c", 2)]

values =  [0, 10, 20]

how could I write a loop that maps the fist element in the tuple from keys to a value in values according to the position in specified in the tuple.

for example this case it should return:

{'a': 20, 'b': 0, 'c': 20}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dict from a list of key, value tuples like so:

```
>>> dict((k,values[i]) for (k,i) in keys)
{'a': 20, 'b': 0, 'c': 20}
```